# Light meter battery compartment won't open. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: light-meter

I recently found a Gossen Variosix Electronic light meter (also known as the Gossen Polysix) at a thrift store. Unfortunately, the battery compartment won't open. I turn the thing on the bottom but the compartment does not loosen.
It's important to note that the enite back is supposed to come off.

[image: Gif of problem]

Comment: "Variosix Electronic 2"?

Comment: @rackandboneman I think so. It looks the same, but lacks the "2" on it.

Comment: Manuals: https://gossen-photo.de/aeltere-geraete-foto/

Comment: @rackandboneman Mine is called the Variosix Electronic, which I think is the same as the Polysix Electronic 2.

Comment: @mattdm How to open it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be obtuse. Do you think there is a secret, non-obvious way to open it and you don't know what that is, or do you think it is fused shut somehow due to some problem and are looking for ways to deal with that?

Comment: @mattdm I'm wondering if there's some obvious way to open it that I'm simply too stupid to think of. Someone somewhere else said the batteries could be bloated.

Comment: Have you tried pulling the entire back off when the screw is as loose as it gets?

Comment: @MichaelC The entire back part is supposed to come off. I can pull the whole meter apart, though I'd prefer to leave that as a last resort.

Comment: @xiota A video on YouTube shows how: https://youtu.be/AKgqAWyLjoA at the 2:58 mark.

Comment: vtc b/c This is a general electronics issue (stuck battery access door) that only incidentally happens to involve photographic equipment (might as well be a television remote).

Comment: @Jrbdog I should have been a bit clearer. The screw is supposed to stay attached to the entire cover, not come completely out. For some light meters, the battery cover encompasses the entire back. What I was trying to say is, "Have you tried removing the cover when the screw gets as loose as it gets?"

Comment: @MichaelC yes. The problem is that the cover isn't coming off.

Comment: Exposure meters and cameras tend to use the "dungeon hole" battery access scheme far more than TV remotes do :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [video](https://youtu.be/AKgqAWyLjoA) you link, I don't think there is some secret, non-obvious way to open the door that you are missing. Most likely something is wrong with the lock screw or the door is stuck.

Possible solutions to consider:

- Use a rubber mallet to tap around the door to loosen stuck components so that the door can be opened.
- Apply moderate dry heat to the area to free components that are stuck because of contraction.
- Use a rubber jar opener to increase friction when you try to open the compartment door.
- Disassemble the device to access the battery compartment and determine why the door was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bayonet lid that will be pushed up, once turned by 90 or so degrees, by the contact spring .... if there is a battery, dead or alive, inside. If there is not, you will need to get a firm grip on it, unless turning it with a screwdriver from below *while holding the device scale side up* already does the trick. Try a magnet, if it is not magnetic ... attach a stick to it with double sided tape, or even actual glue.